script de python en selenium

hola.

me ayudan por favor, con este script que paso chatgpt pero no funciona como se espera.
resumen: lo que se quiere es una automatizacion que descargue de una pagina web que esta la ruta del codigo, un archivo del rango de esa fecha en csv. hasta hay todo bien.  el problema esta en que cuando este codigo lo ejecuta el archivo no se guarda bien.
resultado esperado: se va a ejecutar todo lo dias para descargue el archivo desde el rango del 1 de cada mes hasta el dia actual, se descague en la ruta especifica, la idea es tener una "dataset" local donde se guarden los archivos con los nombres de cada mes.
el problema del codigo acutual:"el problema que tiene este codigo es que remplaza siempre el mismo archivo por el nuevo descargado no importa si es de otro mes diferente o no".
ejemplo de lo que se quiere:
01-2024.csv cada ves que se ejecute el codigo en el mismo mes se remplace el mismo archivo
02-2024.csv  pero cuando sea un nuevo mes se crea otro nuevo archivo con el nombre del mes
03_2024.csv
04-2024.csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
 Configurar la ruta de descarga y nombre de archivo
download_dir = "C:\\Users\\mabad\\Desktop\\Recoleccion"   Cambia esto a la ruta donde deseas guardar el archivo
file_name = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%Y') + ".csv"
file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, file_name)
 Configuración del WebDriver con la ruta de descarga
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": download_dir, "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
 Iniciar el WebDriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
Abrir la página de inicio de sesión
driver.get("https://transprensa.colombiasoftware.net/index.php?page=Despacho.Planrecogida_013.InformeGeneral_007#no-back-button")

Ingresar credenciales
usuario_inp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_Usuario")
contraseña_inp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_Clave")
usuario_inp.send_keys("mabad")
contraseña_inp.send_keys("")
 Clic en el botón de login
i_boton = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_BtnIngresar")
i_boton.click()
 Clic en el botón de continuar (si aplica)
i2_boton = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_BtnContinuar")
i2_boton.click()
Ingresar las fechas en los campos correspondientes
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
fecha_desde_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_fecha_desde")
fecha_hasta_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_fecha_hasta")
fecha_desde_input.send_keys(today)
fecha_hasta_input.send_keys(today)
 Seleccionar "CSV" en el dropdown de tipo de impresión
tipo_impresion_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_remesa_tipoimpresion"))
tipo_impresion_select.select_by_visible_text("CSV")
Hacer clic en el botón de generar
generar_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_ctl1")
generar_button.click()
Esperar a que el archivo se descargue
time.sleep(10)   Ajusta el tiempo de espera según sea necesario
Verificar si el archivo ya existe, y si es así, reemplazarlo
downloaded_files = [f for f in os.listdir(download_dir) if f.endswith(".csv")]
if downloaded_files:
    downloaded_file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, downloaded_files[0])
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)   Eliminar el archivo existente si es necesario
    os.rename(downloaded_file_path, file_path)   Renombrar el archivo descargado
Cerrar el navegador
driver.quit()


soy nuevo que pena, muchas gracias

Si usas chatGPT, nunca aprenderás a programar. Tendrás mil problemas como este, porque chatGPT tampoco sabe programar.

si es verdad, sinceramente estoy iniciando pero necesitaba esta automatizacion con urgencia en el trabajo, la idea es aprender pero aveces el tiempo no me da, pero es lo que se quiere, igual tengo una bases que tengo que mejorar, gracias por tu comentario, es cierto

Obtener el archivo recien descargado haciendo esto:
downloaded_files = [f for f in os.listdir(download_dir) if f.endswith(".csv")]
if downloaded_files:
    downloaded_file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, downloaded_files[0])

es una pésima idea si el directorio de descarga contiene más archivos aparte del recien descargado, por desgracia ChatGPT no lee la documentación:

os.listdir(path='.')
Retorna una lista que contiene los nombres de las entradas en el
directorio dado por path. La lista está en un orden arbitrario...

Si ese directorio contiene los archivos de otros meses downloaded_files[0] puede ser el archivo recien descargado o cualquier otro, no lo podemos asegurar porque la documentación explícitamente menciana que el orden no está determinado.
Si no tienes una forma de determinar el nombre del archivo descargado, te aconsejo usar un directorio diferente para guardar el archivo descargado por el navegador y posteriormente moverlo al directorio final. Lo más apropiado es crear un directorio temporal para ello, de forma que te aseguras de que solo existirá ese archivo en él y además se limpiará trás terminar la ejecución, algo como:
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def download_file(download_dir: str) -> None:
    # Configuración del WebDriver con la ruta de descarga
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {
        "download.default_directory": download_dir,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True
    }
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    # Iniciar el WebDriver
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Abrir la página de inicio de sesión
    driver.get("https://transprensa.colombiasoftware.net/index.php?page=Despacho.Planrecogida_013.InformeGeneral_007#no-back-button")
    
    # Ingresar credenciales
    usuario_inp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_Usuario")
    contraseña_inp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_Clave")
    usuario_inp.send_keys("mabad")
    contraseña_inp.send_keys("")

    # Clic en el botón de login
    i_boton = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_BtnIngresar")
    i_boton.click()

    # Clic en el botón de continuar (si aplica)
    i2_boton = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_BtnContinuar")
    i2_boton.click()

    # Ingresar las fechas en los campos correspondientes
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    fecha_desde_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_fecha_desde")
    fecha_hasta_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_fecha_hasta")
    fecha_desde_input.send_keys(today)
    fecha_hasta_input.send_keys(today)

    # Seleccionar "CSV" en el dropdown de tipo de impresión
    tipo_impresion_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_remesa_tipoimpresion"))
    tipo_impresion_select.select_by_visible_text("CSV")

    # Hacer clic en el botón de generar
    generar_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl0_MainModule_ctl1")
    generar_button.click()

    # Esperar a que el archivo se descargue
    time.sleep(10)   Ajusta el tiempo de espera según sea necesario


download_dir = Path("C:/Users/mabad/Desktop/Recoleccion")
file_name = Path("08-2024").with_suffix(".csv")
file_path = download_dir / file_name

with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_download_path:
    download_file(temp_download_path)
    temp_download_path = Path(temp_download_path)
    try:
        downloaded_file_path = next(temp_download_path.glob("*.csv"))
    except StopIteration:
        print("El archivo no se ha descargado")
    else:
        shutil.copy(
            downloaded_file_path.rename(temp_download_path / file_name),
            download_dir
        )

He agrupado el código encargado de descargar el archivo a la función download_file por legibilidad, lo que interesa para la pregunta es el código fuera de ella.
En esencia creamos un directorio temporal y se lo pasamos a Chrome como directorio de descarga. Luego simplemente vemos si hay algún archivo .csv en él y en caso afirmativo lo renombramos y lo copias al directorio de destino con los archivos de todos los meses. Si el archivo ya existe al copiarlo será reemplazado por el nuevo.

muchas gracias. funciono bien muchas muchas gracias
